# Disabling right click contextmenu with trigger to enable it back

Tags: javascript, html, right-click

I want to be able to disable the right click menu on my website, which I'm doing with the following:

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

How would I re-enable right clicking, such as when the user clicks on a button elsewhere on the page? Maybe something like

```
function() {
  $('body').unbind();
}
```

---

Thanks, the code below works great:

#### HTML

```
<div class="listener">
    <button onclick="stopjs()" id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript code

```
function prevent(e) {
    console.log('preventing');
    e.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener("contextmenu", prevent);

function stopjs() {
    document.removeEventListener("contextmenu", prevent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to save a reference to the function you pass into `addEventListener`, and then you'll be able to remove it later:

```js
function prevent(e) {
  console.log('preventing');
  e.preventDefault();
}
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", prevent);

setTimeout(() => {
  document.removeEventListener("contextmenu", prevent);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I am not so .js savvy, how would the whole code looked, the re enable button will be hidden with css, so only certain people will know about it! Thank you!

Comment: Just add a click listener to that button instead of using `setTimeout`, eg `btn.onclick = () => ...`